# Trying to install livewallpaper

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have tried everything, installing from the deb (getting the "dependency is not satisfiable" error) as well as from the ppa on the command line. I'd be grateful for any pointers. I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 on an HP Pavillion laptop (64 bit). Thanks in advance,
Bernard

Here is the full install history:

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable
[sudo] password for bernard: 
 Stable releases of LiveWallpaper
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~fyrmir/+archive/ubuntu/livewallpaper-stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpk7ndat33/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpk7ndat33/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key B2D77075 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpk7ndat33/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key B2D77075: public key "Launchpad PPA for Maximilian Schnarr" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
bernard@bernard-HP-Pavilion-dv3-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily InRelease                                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease                                    
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease [64,4 kB]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release.gpg                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner Sources                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner i386 Packages                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release                                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner Translation-en                   
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources [17,9 kB]          
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources [1.922 B]    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources [4.714 B]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources [2.854 B]    
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages [55,1 kB]   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                          
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10,9 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en                          
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages [25,9 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5.859 B]
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources             
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages [54,3 kB]   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages [10,8 kB]
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages       
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages [26,0 kB]
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en      
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages [6.052 B]
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources                             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources                       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/restricted Sources              
Get:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/multiverse Sources [826 B]   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en_US                       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en                          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources                       
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages         
  404  Not Found
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages              
  404  Not Found
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/main Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/universe Sources
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/main i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/main Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com wily-proposed/universe Translation-en
Fetched 288 kB in 6s (46,1 kB/s)                                               
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/muscovy/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/muscovy/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
bernard@bernard-HP-Pavilion-dv3-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install livewallpaper livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator livewallpaper-nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package livewallpaper
E: Unable to locate package livewallpaper-config
E: Unable to locate package livewallpaper-indicator
E: Unable to locate package livewallpaper-nautilus
```

Comment: Could you please describe in detail what you have already tried and add the exact and full outputs/error messages of those commands to your question? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for picking this up, here you go (and I apologise for not doing this before, I'm a Ubuntu newbie...). Here you go:
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
$ sudo apt-get update

Comment: That's not everything I requested. To troubleshoot the error you encounter, we need the full output of `sudo apt-get install livewallpaper`. Please [edit] your question to provide it, do not post it as comment. It will get an ugly and unreadable formatting otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, will do..

Comment: And you are sure you ran the `apt-get install` command *after* the `add-apt-repository` and `apt-get update` command? Did any of those two others print an error message?

Comment: Yes, I did it in the order as above. I got lots of 404 errors, although the repositories are there (I checked). This only happens with livewallpaper.

Comment: Please add the full outputs of the other two commands to your question then as well. We need to troubleshoot those errors then. Was your internet connection working when you ran them? You can also try to run `sudo apt-get update` again and try the installation once more afterwards. This helps only if a temporarily broken internet connection was the problem though, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried to add the full output, but that includes lots of url's and I can't post more than 2 yet. It basically looks like it can't find the repositories. I did download the dep, but then I got "dependency not satisfiable", and yes I did check all the boxes in "update"....

Comment: You should be able to post the output if you format it as code. Therefore paste it into the question editor, then select it again and hit CTRL+K or click the **`{}`** button. It will indent every line with 4 spaces and mark them as code this way. If that doesn't work either, please upload the output to https://www.pastebin.com and copy the link here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install `livewallpaper` from those PPAs (`ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable` and `ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily`), because neither of them contains a build for your Ubuntu version (15.10 Wily).

You need to find another PPA which supports the latest Ubuntu version as well.

To remove those two unusable PPAs you added, run the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
```

The same problem (no builds for your Ubuntu version 15.10/Wily) also applies on another PPA you have installed (`ppa:muscovy/ppa`). You should remove it as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:muscovy/ppa
```

Comment: Aha! Many many thanks, I can look forward to some sleep now  ;)

Comment: @BernardFarkin Instead of writing "thank you", you should accept the answer to mark your problem as solved. Please make sure you have read the AskUbuntu [tour], where you learn the most important rules and buttons of our site within two minutes. Thanks!